# listView.addHeaderView() giving "null pointer exception"

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to add header to my list view .

Below is my code for achieve the same..

```
     ListView listView;
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
     //View header = View.inflate(this  , R.layout.header, null);
     LayoutInflater ll = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View v2 = ll.inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);


    listView.addHeaderView(v2);
```

But  "listView.addHeaderView(v2)" this line giving "NullPointerException"

Please let me know what can be done to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Which one is null, listView or v2?

Answer (score 4):

just try this:

```
listView.addHeaderView(LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, null));
```

instead of :

```
LayoutInflater ll = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v2 = ll.inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
listView.addHeaderView(v2);
```

Comment: Could you explain me why?